# BackupAgent doing nothing

Tags: android, android-backup-service

Manifest:

```
<manfiest package="com.backme"  ... />
    <application android:backupAgent="PrefsBackupAgent" .../>
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key"
            android:value="12345...." />
```

Code:

```
public class PrefsBackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d("PrefsBackupAgent","Backingup");
        SharedPreferencesBackupHelper helper = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, PlacesConstants.SHARED_PREFERENCE_FILE);
        addHelper(PlacesConstants.SP_KEY_FOLLOW_LOCATION_CHANGES, helper);
    }
}
```

Does it matter that my `PrefsBackupAgent` is not at the top level of `com.backme` but at `com.backme.utils` ?   And FYI, I'm not seeing the "Backingup" in the logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute *android:backupAgent* requires a fully qualified class name or a period (it is appended to the package name specified in the  element) as specified [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#agent/)!